# Can't get String which is entered into Edit Text in ExpandableListView(Not the usual Focus issue)

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

Hey so basically I have a Sign-in/Register screen for an app and I have to make it using an ExpandableListView as shown.

Based on the position of the child in a group I have inflated different views. So for positions 0 and 1, I have inflated 2 different EditText boxes.

My problem is I can't get the text that is typed in both the boxes.

The box allows me to type continuously but when I click the Sign-In button, the strings I get from the username and password boxes using getText are both null!

[Sign-In screen shot http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/5544/shot000005w.png](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/5544/shot000005w.png)
[Username Toast is blank http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/3825/shot000006y.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/3825/shot000006y.png)
[Password Toast is blank http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/8804/shot000007.png](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/8804/shot000007.png)

Here's the get getChildView from the CustomExpandableAdapter:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   v = null;

   position = 0;
   position=getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);

   if(position==0) //draw the username editbox
   {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.username, parent, false);
    Element c = (Element)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
    username = (EditText)v.findViewById( R.id.username);

    if( username != null )          
         username.setHint(c.getElement());

    }
   else if(position==1)
   {
       if(convertView == inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, parent, false))
        return convertView;
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, parent, false);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, parent, false);
        Element c = (Element)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
        password = (EditText)v.findViewById( R.id.password);
    if( password != null )          
         password.setHint(c.getElement());

   }
   else if (position>1023 && position<1028)
   {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false);
        Element c = (Element)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
        et = (EditText)v.findViewById( R.id.et);


    if( et != null )            
         et.setHint(c.getElement());
   }

   else if(position==1028)
    {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gender, parent, false);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
          context, R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        s = (Spinner) v.findViewById( R.id.spinner_gend );
        s.setAdapter( adapter );
    }

   else if(position==2)  //Forgot Button
   {
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot, parent, false);
       Button forgot = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.fpb);
       forgot.setOnClickListener(this);


   }


   else if(position==3)  //Sign-in Button
   {
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_button, parent, false);
       ImageButton sign_in = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
       sign_in.setOnClickListener(this); 

}
   return v;
}
```

and later on in the code I have the onClick of the Sign in button:

```
case R.id.sign_in_button: {
        String user_name = username.getText().toString();
        String pass_word=password.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(context,"u:"+ user_name, 3000).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "p:"+pass_word, 3000).show();
                    //Other unrelated Database Code


    }
```

Here the Toasts always show just u: and p:

Someone help!

Comment: First of all my suggestion is to try using getText() method for editText and get the data entered.Secondly ,I wish to ask you how did u solve the issue of typing text inside the edit text within expanded list view . I am still stuck with this issue and also if possible can u post your code so i could learn from it because i also need to create a dynamic form with editText and spinners which repeats depending on the number of records to be entered .Please help me if you ca because my job depends on it.I am not creating a new topic because too many restrictions adn its more or less likely to be

Comment: @user1435153
Hey man, thanks but I used a TextWatcher. Check out this post to see how to resolve the issues with an EditText box in an ExpandableListView(or a ListView)

(http://codersmusings.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/edittext-in-expandablelistview/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used a TextWatcher(which didn't work properly before this)
The code is here:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    user_name=s.toString();
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```