# Getting the value of edittext in expandable list view on button click in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am developing an **ExpandableListview** with textview and editext like follwing.

[image]

Now I am using this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

But the most important thing that I want is to get all **editext** value should get on 
**SAVE** button click.

My code are as follows:-

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.recoveryreminder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.adapter.ExpandableListAdapter;
import com.constants.RecordData;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    Button Save;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entry_record);

    //  record = new RecordData();

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
                listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                RecoverData record1=new RecoverData();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Name is:" + record1.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Purpose is:" + record1.getPurpose(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Basic Info");
        listDataHeader.add("Addtional Info");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> basic = new ArrayList<String>();
        basic.add("Name");
        basic.add("Purpose");

        List<String> additional = new ArrayList<String>();
        additional.add("Payment Date");
        additional.add("Payment Due Date");
        additional.add("Payment Due Time");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), basic); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), additional);

    }
}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
 package com.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.constants.RecordData;
import com.recoveryreminder.R;
import com.recoveryreminder.RecoverData;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements TextWatcher{

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private ArrayList<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    String name,purpose;



    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }



    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        EditText editetext = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItemEditext);
        editetext.addTextChangedListener(this);
        editTextList.add(editetext);

        /**/






        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name=editTextList.get(0).getText().toString();
        purpose=editTextList.get(1).getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("Name is"+name);
        System.out.println("purpose is"+purpose);

        //Toast.makeText(_context, "Name"+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(_context, "Purpose"+purpose, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

**list-item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lblListItemEditext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >


    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list-group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**entry-record.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel_button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_font_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/save_button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_font_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>




        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
             android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:layout_margin="@dimen/record_fields_margin" 
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: what is the problem?? edittext.getText().tostring should do the trick

Comment: Its not like that i cannot find out the value for each editetext differently.I just show my code so you can get an idea

Comment: @IllegalArgument:Look at the code in the link it just only disply an textview with name and i am adding an editext in that but i want to get each editext value seperately with its position.

Comment: You can find your solution as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700143/cant-get-string-which-is-entered-into-edit-text-in-expandablelistviewnot-the-u

Answer (score 0):

Add a focuschangelistener for the edittext and where u will get the position and value inside each edittext and then save those value to hashmap and then iterate that map on save button click.